# How do you enable the app-context-dependent touch bar for Photoshop on the new 2016 rmbp

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

How do you enable the app-context-dependent touch bar for Photoshop on the new 2016 rmbp?

I've just updated to the latest CC software 2017.0 releases - and not seeing the custom touch bar. A Google search yields a ton of news article demonstrations without actually telling you how to enable it.

A corollary question is - which are the context-specific touchbar apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run Photoshop CC 2017 Version 18.0.1?

From the release note:

> Use the Touch Bar with Photoshop - Photoshop now supports Touch Bar,
>   the multitouch display at the top of the new MacBook Pro keyboard;
>   Touch Bar support in Photoshop is currently a technology preview
>   feature

Adobe said it is an experimental feature. It could be that this functions is not turned on automatically.

You can turn it on here: Preferences > Technology Previews > Enable Touch Bar

Comment: I noticed 18.0.1 just came out :)